# ArgumentException "Value was invalid" when calling RSACryptoServiceProvider.SignData

Tags: security, rsa, sha256

I'm getting a System.ArgumentException "Value was invalid" when calling RSACryptoServiceProvider.SignData with the following code:

```
var csp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)_certificate.PrivateKey;
string simpleName = CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256");
return csp.SignData(data, simpleName);
```

The code is from a third party sample so it should work in the right circumstances. It seems it could be caused by my OS but I haven't found a solution so thought I'd post here to see if someone can help?

.NET Framework: 3.5
OS: Microsoft Windows Server 2003 R2 Enterprise Edition Service Pack 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link provided:

"The root cause for this is that the CryptoConfig does not understand SHA256CryptoServiceProvider. It was added as part of the green bits in .NET 3.5, and due to layering restrictions the red bits (such as mscorlib.dll where RSACryptoServiceProvider lives) does not know about its existence...

If you are using .Net Framework 4.0 then the resolution is to modify the “machine.config” file at:

```
%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.xxxxx\ CONFIG  -> for x86
%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.xxxxx\CONFIG -> for x64
```

If you are using .Net Framework 3.5 then the resolution is to modify the “machine.config” file at:

```
%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.xxxxx\ CONFIG  -> for x86
%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.xxxxx\CONFIG -> for x64
```

Here is the entry that you need to make at the "machine.config" file for supporting SHA256CryptoServiceProvider, SHA256Cng, SHA384CryptoServiceProvider, SHA384Cng, SHA512CryptoServiceProvider, and SHA512Cng."

```
<mscorlib>
    <cryptographySettings>
      <cryptoNameMapping>
        <cryptoClasses>
          <cryptoClass SHA256CSP="System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256CryptoServiceProvider, System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
          <cryptoClass SHA256CNG="System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Cng, System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
          <cryptoClass SHA384CSP="System.Security.Cryptography.SHA384CryptoServiceProvider, System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
          <cryptoClass SHA384CNG="System.Security.Cryptography.SHA384Cng, System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
          <cryptoClass SHA512CSP="System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512CryptoServiceProvider, System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
          <cryptoClass SHA512CNG="System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Cng, System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        </cryptoClasses>
        <nameEntry name="SHA256" class="SHA256CSP" />
        <nameEntry name="SHA256CryptoServiceProvider" class="SHA256CSP" />
        <nameEntry name="System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256CryptoServiceProvider" class="SHA256CSP" />
        <nameEntry name="SHA256Next" class="SHA256CNG" />
        <nameEntry name="SHA256Cng" class="SHA256CNG" />
        <nameEntry name="System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Cng" class="SHA256CNG" />
        <nameEntry name="SHA384" class="SHA384CSP" />
        <nameEntry name="SHA384CryptoServiceProvider" class="SHA384CSP" />
        <nameEntry name="System.Security.Cryptography.SHA384CryptoServiceProvider" class="SHA384CSP" />
        <nameEntry name="SHA384Next" class="SHA384CNG" />
        <nameEntry name="SHA384Cng" class="SHA384CNG" />
        <nameEntry name="System.Security.Cryptography.SHA384Cng" class="SHA384CNG" />
        <nameEntry name="SHA512" class="SHA512CSP" />
        <nameEntry name="SHA512CryptoServiceProvider" class="SHA512CSP" />
        <nameEntry name="System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512CryptoServiceProvider" class="SHA512CSP" />
        <nameEntry name="SHA512Next" class="SHA512CNG" />
        <nameEntry name="SHA512Cng" class="SHA512CNG" />
        <nameEntry name="System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Cng" class="SHA512CNG" />
      </cryptoNameMapping>
      <oidMap>
        <oidEntry OID="2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1" name="SHA256" />
        <oidEntry OID="2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1" name="SHA256Next" />
        <oidEntry OID="2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.2" name="SHA384" />
        <oidEntry OID="2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.2" name="SHA384Next" />
        <oidEntry OID="2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.3" name="SHA512" />
        <oidEntry OID="2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.3" name="SHA512Next" />
      </oidMap>
    </cryptographySettings>
  </mscorlib>
```

Link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2010/08/18/getting-a-system-argumentexception-value-was-invalid-when-trying-to-sign-data-using-sha256cryptoserviceprovider.aspx

Comment: Hi , I am facing the same issue .I have copied same into my mechine config but it is not working .  Are there any other changes to do.|
This is my code
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28362788/system-argumentexception-on-windows-server-2003-os-iis-6-while-rsacryptoservic

Comment: @KyasaMadhavi see my comment below for a better approach

Answer (score 5):

After doing more digging around, I've manged to find a more suitable solution than editing the machine.config file.  You can specify the OID for the algorithm that you're interested in using yourself, and then pass that value to the RSA provider like so:

```
public static string Sign(string data)
{   
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(); 
    HashAlgorithm algorithm = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();
    const string sha256Oid = "2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1";

    byte[] dataBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
    byte[] hashBytes= algorithm.ComputeHash(dataBytes);
    byte[] signedBytes = rsaProvider.SignHash(hashBytes, sha256Oid);
    string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(signedBytes);

    return signature;
}
```